# Angular forEach function troubles

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to run a angular.forEach function on values of a query string in a URL.

Consider the following:

`domain.com?quote=10&quote=20`

Doing `$scope.selectedQuotes = $stateParams.quote;` works as expected and outputs `["10", "20"]`, creating an array.

But with the same function on:

`domain.com?quote=10`

This outputs '10' as a string and runs the forEach on each character.

Here is the full code:

```
$scope.selectedQuotes = $stateParams.quote;
console.log($scope.selectedQuotes);

angular.forEach($scope.selectedQuotes, function(quote){
}
```

So the question is, how do you get it so it always classes the value as an array?

Comment: This seems like the expected behavior to me. You'll have to detect whether it's an array or a string, and act accordingly.

Comment: @KevinB docs had already stated the same.. I've added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK... adding:

```
params: {
   quote: { array: true }
}
```

To the state controller solved this.

Comment: Yep.  Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

[**Docs**](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider) has already stated that

> if multiple values for a single parameter are present in the URL
>   (e.g.: /foo?bar=1&bar=2&bar=3) then the values are mapped to an array
>   (e.g.: { foo: [ '1', '2', '3' ] }). However, if only one value is
>   present (e.g.: /foo?bar=1) then the value is treated as single value
>   (e.g.: { foo: '1' }).

So even if you have type of variable as `array: true` inside state like you have `quote` parameter of state as an array. When single value appears against `quote`, It will be considered as `string` like `'10'`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
$scope.selectedQuotes = $stateParams.quote;
console.log($scope.selectedQuotes);

angular.forEach($scope.selectedQuotes, function(quote){
    return quote.map(function(newArray) {
        return newArray;
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 if(Array.isArray($scope.selectedQuotes)){
 //itar with angular.forEach  
   } else{ 
  $scope.selectedQuotes=[$scope.selectedQuotes]
  // then itar with angular.forEach
 }
```